# FindOne never gets executed Meteor js

Tags: mongodb, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

I have been on this for a while. The problem with is is that this line of code never get executed `let userSchool = SchoolDb.findOne({slug: Session.get('ReceivedSlug')});` When I logged on the console I see the the slug is dynamic as it is suppose to be pull the record from the db. What am I to do right?
The oncreated template

```
Template.view.onCreated(function () {
    Session.set('ReceivedSlug', FlowRouter.getParam('myslug'));
    this.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('SingleSchool', Session.get('ReceivedSlug'));
    });
});
```

The helper function

```
singleSchool: function () {
        if (Meteor.userId()) {
            console.log('reactive this ---- ' +Session.get('ReceivedSlug'));
            let userSchool = SchoolDb.findOne({slug: Session.get('ReceivedSlug')});
            if (!userSchool) {
                Bert.alert('School not present', 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
            } else {
                console.log('school name ----' +userSchool.slug);
                return userSchool;
            }
        }   
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether the subscription has fetched data. Also console out inside publish that whether data gets published when slug changed.

Use below code to check if subscription is working

```
Meteor.subscribe('SingleSchool', Session.get('ReceivedSlug'), { 
    onReady: function(){
        console.log(SchoolDb.find({}).fetch());
    }
});
```